# MacOS Mission Control Shortcuts not working with Chrome Remote Desktop

Tags: windows, macos, google-chrome, mission-control, chrome-remote-desktop

**Note:** Somewhat related to [Chrome Remote Desktop Keyboard ShortCut Needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13518963/chrome-remote-desktop-keyboard-shortcut-needed)

### The Problem

I found using the Chrome Remote Desktop that the `Ctrl` key is not forwarded or recognized on the Mac as Mission Control Commands.

### Workaround Attempt

So I started using the [Chrome Remote Desktop WebApp beta](https://remotedesktop.google.com/access) on Windows 10, because it has key mapping!

I found that my best key mapping is to map the `Crtl` key to `CMD`.  Which works well in the apps that I regularly use on the Mac for cut/copy/paste, etc. Yay! (this makes them work pretty much like my windows equivalents)

But the Mac Mission Control Shortcuts are still not working, because they depend on the `Ctrl` key.

Using System `Preferences->Keyboard->Shortcuts`, I remapped the Mission Control Shortcuts so they use `Shift+CMD` as the prefix to the arrow commands instead of `Ctrl`.

**Note:** I entered these keyboard mappings from my Chrome Remote Desktop session.  So I know that `Shift+CMD+arrows` are making it over to the Mac.

### Workaround Fail

When I use the Mac directly `Shift+CMD+arrows` does exactly what I expect, the Mission Control actions get performed.

When I use Chrome Remote Desktop I get nothing.

### Questions

- Is there some kind of setting I need to enable so that Mission Control will intercept shortcuts coming from Chrome Remote Desktop WebApp?
- Is there maybe a better way to enable Mission Control Shortcuts over Chrome Remote Desktop?

Comment: Have you ever found a solution?

Comment: sadly, no.  I guess I have just gotten used to the keyboard issues on the Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did find a solution and I posted it under a new question, forgot I had this question hanging out there. (newbie error)

Here it is: [MacOS VSCode shift+cmd+left & right/up/down not working](https://superuser.com/questions/1477847/macos-vscode-shiftcmdleft-right-up-down-not-working)