# MacOS VSCode shift+cmd+left & right/up/down not working

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-code

On MacOS I was not getting the `shift+cmd+left/right/up/down`to work.

#### Repro:

1. Open VSCode
2. Go to `Code->preferences->keyboard shortcuts`
3. Click on keyboard symbol on far right.
4. press `shift+cmd+left/up/down/right`.

**Result**: none of them are interpreted. All that is displayed is `shift+cmd+`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Fix:

Hunted around...
Discovered that Mission Control was using all of these keys.  So I remapped them all to other Function keys (that I do not use in editing).

There are 2 places to check:

1. `System preferences->Mission Control`
2. `System preferences->Keyboard->Shortcuts->Mission Control`

After remapping, it still did not work!

Close and **restart Visual Studio Code** and then it works!

Posted here so others do not have to struggle with this.